# Density function of a bernoulli variable

Tags: probability, density-function, bernoulli-distribution

How to find the density function of a bernoulli variable `y =1, -1` ? i know the formula for `y=1,0` but i want it for `y =1, -1`

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: This variable has no density.  Its distribution is given by two probabilities (which, since they must sum to unity, is determined by either one of them).  Those probabilities remain the same when you relabel the values.  There's nothing to find.  When the values of $y$ are in $\{-1,1\}$ this is called a [Rademacher variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Rademacher+variable).

Comment: @whuber I think one could say that discrete random variables have densities w.r.t. the counting measure.

Comment: @statmerkur That is true but If the student is not familiar with measure-theory then IMV it is better not use the word "density" in the context of discrete distributions. This to avoid confusion and to emphasize the difference between discrete and continuous.

Comment: @drhab I agree. But not using the word "density" is different from stating that "[t]his variable has no density".

Comment: @statmerkur Unfortunately, your use of "density" is so broad as to make the term useless: every probability distribution function has a density with respect to some measure (such as the one it determines).  When "density" appears in a novice question it's rarely productive to insist on interpreting the word in such generality.

Comment: @whuber Whether this makes the term "density" useless is IMHO debatable. I don't insist on interpreting it in such generality but rather said that it would be possible to do so. Besides, I deliberately used the more common term "probability mass function" in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Bernoulli random variable $X$ has support $\left\{0,1\right\}$. A random variable $Y$ with support $\left\{-1,1\right\}$ is thus not a Bernoulli random variable. However, by considering $Y = 2X-1$, or $X=\left(1+Y\right)/2$, where $X\sim \mathop{\mathrm{Bern}}\left(p\right)$, we immediately find the probability mass function you are looking for:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathop{p_Y}\left(y\right) =
\mathop{\mathbb{P}}\left(Y=y\right) 
&= 
\begin{cases}
p^{\left(1+y\right)/2} \left(1-p\right)^{1-\left(1+y\right)/2} & ,y\in \left\{-1,1\right\} \\
0 & ,\text{otw.}
\end{cases}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
p^{\left(1+y\right)/2} \left(1-p\right)^{\left(1-y\right)/2} & ,y\in \left\{-1,1\right\} \\
0 & ,\text{otw.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$